# Two-column blogspot layout from scratch: how?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm trying to make my first HTML/CSS blogspot (new format) layout from scratch, and it's proving to be hard. I'm used to making 2-column layouts be it using float, flex or what have you, but even with display:inline-block, divs set to border box 30% and 70%, the sidebar with the widgets just doesn't stay, well, on the side. I looked around for other solutions but nothing solved my problem, and I wanted to keep relative positioning because of the footer and because the height of the content in the page will always vary. Sorry if this is a noobish question but this is my first time dealing with xml and this layout is more than delayed because I can't get around it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Found out... the problem is that I messed up copying and pasting xml I didn't understand, I ended up misplacing  and ruining everything. :P So yes, actually every usual method mentioned below probably works. It's now working on flexbox: http://kawaiisugoibakanekos.blogspot.com.br/
Thanks all who tried to help!

Comment: The first solution were `<table>`s. Than came `box` model. And now we have `flexbox`. It took web development over 20 years of trial and error to get here. Your question is not noobish. But it's way too broad. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. You are supposed to come here with specific problems you don't understand or need clarified. Not with tasks or to-do lists.

Comment: Wow, first of all, thank you so much for being understanding. The problem is, it's not 2 column layout I don't get, it's more that I don't understand Blogspot templates because of the xml so I can't see what's conflicting.
I do two-column layout by the float or inline-block on a main block methods, which always worked. However my methods simply don't work here. I tried flexbox but it still didn't work. I'll put my code on a pastebin to make it more clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Providing more details about the exact concept or problem you want cleared is the right way to go on StackOverflow. If you ask the right questions, the right answers will make their way to you quite fast.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I just wanted to know really if there's anything wrong with my code that I'm not seeing, and if not, it's probably something in the Blogspot xml I'll have to fiddle it. Sorry for not explaining before and thank you.

Comment: I found it... after all, it was a stupid mistake I did. I reedited the code to show a leaner version and then I found out. So sorry for bothering needlessly... in conclusion, yes, these methods do work normally for blogspot layouts and it's now working. Thanks a lot!!